# Web.config connection strings being overridden in all but one virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config, connection-string

My ASP.NET application hosted on Azure has 4 APIs running under virtual directories. The configuration of these virtual directories on Azure are all identical in format. There is a connection string of the same name defined in the root application web.config and all of the virtual directories' web.config. Connection strings are all defined in the same way with no  statements.

For some reason, one of the virtual directory applications complains that the connection string has already been defined and yet the other 3 are OK with it.

Comment: How are you hosting this in Azure? App Service? Cloud Services? VM?

Comment: Azure App Service.

Comment: Is the Connection String section the 3 web.config files identical? Any differences at all?